# Vue component not loaded with Plugin syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this Vue plugin that is not working:

```js
import _Vue from "vue";
import particles from "./Particles.vue";

const VueParticles = (Vue: typeof _Vue, options: unknown) => {
    _Vue.component('Particles', particles);
};

export { particles as ParticlesComponent };
export default VueParticles;
```

It builds, but if I try to use it, it doesn't load the component and the app returns me this error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/App.vue

And I load the plugin like this:

```js
import Particles from "particles.vue";

Vue.use(Particles);
```

But if I load the component using the `Vue.component` syntax, it's working, like this:

```js
import { ParticlesComponent } from "particles.vue";

Vue.component("Particles", ParticlesComponent);
```

This is the template I'm using:

```html
<Particles id="tsparticles" :options="options" :particlesInit="particlesInit" :particlesLoaded="particlesLoaded"/>
```

You can try to replicate the issue following these steps:

- Clone [tsParticles](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles) `dev` branch with: `git clone https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles.git --branch dev`
- Run `yarn && npx lerna bootstrap && npx lerna run build`
- Go to `demo/vue` folder
- Run `yarn serve` and open http://localhost:8080, everything should work (an animated background should start animating)
- Edit `src/App.vue` commenting the working `Vue.component` and restoring the `Vue.use`
- Rerun `yarn serve` and open http://localhost:8080, the background this time is not appearing

I just switched from `yarn` workspaces to standard `yarn` for big issues with the node dependencies in the whole project

I don't understand why it broke like this.

I also tried an external `Vue.js` app instead of the demo one inside the project but nothing changed.

The component is using `vue-property-decorator` but I tried switching to the `Vue.extend` syntax and nothing changed so I reverted to the previous class code.

Comment: why are you using `_Vue` instead of `Vue`

Comment: It's just a type, I changed it to `Vue` and renamed the variable name to `vue` but nothing has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [plugin file should be exporting an object with an `install` function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin), but your plugin just exports the function itself. Also, the `install` function's argument should be used in the body (i.e., `Vue` is the argument name, so the body should contain `Vue.component()`).

The fix should look like this:

```js
const VueParticles = {
  install(Vue: typeof _Vue, options: unknown) {
    Vue.component('Particles', particles);
  }
};

export default VueParticles;
```

Comment: Using the `dev` branch?

Comment: I solved the build errors and it didn't work in a clean install. I tried copying the Vue component and demo folders away from the project, but same error if I use the plugin.

Comment: Your [plugin code](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/blob/5295819/components/vue/src/Particles/index.ts#L6) still uses the `Vue` import instead of the `vue` argument.

Comment: Thanks!! Using the argument totally fixed it!